# retrieve values from one database server and store them in other database server using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am working on a project 
How can I retrieve values from one database server and store them in other database server using PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible through the insert select combination

consider following example.

```
 INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
 SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
 FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```

Comment: OP talks about 2 different database servers. How could this be the accepted answer ?

Answer (score 2):

If the databases are on the same host, and the user has access to both, you can easily swap the data like this:

```
INSERT INTO database2.table1 (*fields*) 
SELECT *fields* FROM database1.table1
```

Replace *fields* by the list of fields in the table.
Note that this query will grab the full table and might take some time.

If the databases are on different hosts or for any other reason you cannot connect to both with only one connection, do this:

```
$dbh1 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password); 
$dbh2 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password, true); 
//the fourth parameter makes sure that a new link is opened as if the parameters are the same, php will grab the old connection instead of creating one.

mysql_select_db('database1', $dbh1);
mysql_select_db('database2', $dbh2);
```

Then to query database 1, do this:

```
mysql_query('select * from tablename', $dbh1);
```

and for database 2:

```
mysql_query('select * from tablename', $dbh2);
```

... Or in PDO ...

```
$database1 = new PDO('mysql:dbname=database1name;host=127.0.0.1', 'username', 'password');
$database2 = new PDO('mysql:dbname=database2name;host=127.0.0.1', 'username', 'password');
$result1 = $database1->query("select * from tablename");
$result2 = $database2->query("select * from tablename");
```

Comment: Please use `PDO` instead of mysql_ methods.

Comment: you used `select` query for both databases !

Comment: You are right, the goal here was to show it is possible to connect to 2 databases and query them in the same script even if they are distant. I left the logic for the update to the OP.

Comment: @Salketer, the OP talks about 2 different DB servers not just 2 DBs, right ?

Comment: And yet the accepted answer only answered the question for 2 databases on the same server. But why are you digging up this question? Is the answer lacking for a similar problem you are having?